# Parse datetime in SQL Server with Time Zone information

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime, parsing

I have a datetime taken from my system in the following format inside an Excel table: "2021-11-02 09:54:52 EDT". SQL Server can't parse the timezone.
Is there a way for SQL Server to parse this timezone or do I need to remove it from the CSV, or should I parse it in Excel?

Comment: How are you sending the data to SQL Server? Also, Excel does very weird things to DateTime values and doesn't always store or export them in the same format you see on the screen, so make sure what is sent to SQL Server matches your view in the sheet.

Comment: Is your data restricted to a known set of time zones, or do they at least use the ISO standard names, because [some of those acronyms are not unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) (e.g. CST could be American Central Standard Time or China Standard Time)?

Comment: SQL Server has a far easier time parsing *offsets*, so see if you can change the input data to include those (i.e. `09:54:42-04:00`) instead of time zone abbrevations/names.

Comment: Also please be very specific about what version of SQL Server you're using. Newer versions have more advanced features like `AT TIME ZONE` but it's not fair for people to spend time using them to come up with solutions for you if you can't use them.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I guess I never understand why people persist in trying to get SQL Server to do things it isn't good at. Why can people not get their data into the correct format *before* it arrives in SQL Server? This applies across the board: dates, numbers, JSON, XML, columns that need splitting. SQL Server excels at querying well-formed data, it doesn't excel at mangling strings. There are much better languages for this, even Excel can do it better

Comment: @Charlieface Don't forget about doing filesystem things or sending e-mail or reading the registry or storing images. I think the biggest problem is so many people just see SQL Server as another application.